# Getting a Time from a string in a specific format

Tags: c#

I need to get the time out of this string format I get in the _event.EventText, how can I get it, I believe it has similar topics, but I did not manage to find the right to solve my problem.

This is a text from which I need to extract text and time. ("09:00:00\nText")

[image]

I got the text to get it in this way:

```
  var value = _event.EventText;
  var text = value.Substring(value.LastIndexOf('\n') + 1);
```

now I need some time, how can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `TimeSpan.Parse`, or [`TimeSpan.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

> Converts the specified string representation of a time interval to its
>   `TimeSpan` equivalent and returns a value that indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded.

```
if (TimeSpan.TryParse(text , out var time))
{
    Console.WriteLine(time);
    // yehaa 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a better idea to split by newline. By doing so, you can retrieve both parts (before and after the newline):

```
var myString = "09:00:00\nTekst!";
var split = myString.Split('\n');

var timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(split[0]);
var text = split[1];
Console.WriteLine(timeSpan);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
var value = _event.EventText;
var text = value.Split('\n')[0]; // 0 Index return the time
```

Answer (score 0):

Time string:

```
string timeString= value.Substring(0,8);
```

Time:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(value.Substring(0,8));
```

Time format:

```
string time24 = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); //"09:35:37"
string time12 = dateTime.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"); //"9:35:37 AM"
```